# head cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: java, error-handling

The get() method takes a configuration as an input and returns the record of that configuration if it is in the hashtable already. The variables defined and method I have is as follows:

```
/*** Variables ***/
private LinearNode<TTTRecord> head = null;
private LinearNode<TTTRecord> current;
private LinearNode<TTTRecord> Hashnode;
private LinkedList list;
private LinkedList[] hashtable;
private int numElements;
private int index;
private String[] configArray;

public void remove(String config) throws InexistentKeyException {
    index = hashfunction(config);

    current = hashtable[index].head;

    if (hashtable[index].isEmpty())
        throw new InexistentKeyException(config);

    if (current.getElement().getConfiguration().equals(config)) {
        hashtable[index].remove(current.getElement());
        return;
    }
    while ((current.getNext() != null) && (current.getNext().getElement() != null)) {
        if (current.getElement().getConfiguration().equals(config)) {
            hashtable[index].remove(current.getElement());
            return;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    if (current.getElement() == null && current.getNext() == null)
        throw new InexistentKeyException(config);

}
```

I am not sure why the line `current = hashtable[index].head;` is showing the error `head cannot be resolved or is not a field` and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using `java.util.LinkedList` or your own variant?

Comment: I imported java.util.LinkedList

Comment: Right, so in Java you need to be explicit with your generic types otherwise it will default to `Object`. Since you did not specify the generic type contained within your `hashTable`, Java is making the assumption that it contains anything, in which case it is right that `head` is not a valid property of the super class of everything (`Object`). You need to do `LinkedList<MyType>[] hashTable`. I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashtable is an array of linked lists.

When you do `hashtable[index]`, this gives you a linkedList. Now to get the first element in the linked list, you use `LinkedList::getFirst`.

```
hashtable[index].getFirst();
```

If the Linkedlists themselves store something useful like a custom type, you need to specify that in the declaration of the field otherwise Java will assume they contain anything and will treat them all as `Object`'s.

```
private LinkedList<MyType>[] hashTable;
```

Then you can do `current = hashtable[index].getFirst().head;` (assuming `MyType` has an accessible field called `head`).